# IP_MULTICAST_TTL and windows7

Tags: sockets, windows-7, setsockopt

My application is creating an UDP socket and setting some options. One of the option is `IP_MULTICAST_TTL.`

When the application is running on windows 7, and I observe the traffic on the wire with wireshark, I can see that the TTL is always 1, meaning that the `setsockopt()` is not having any effect (it does not return an error though).

Digging into the code I found that `IP_MULTICAST_TTL` value is 10 on Windows 7, 3 on other Windows versions.

If I force the value to be 3 on Windows 7, `setsockopt()` works just fine and wireshark is reporting the right value.

I found this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257460 and I verify that I'm including Ws2tcpip.h after Winsock2.h and that i am linking against Ws2_32.lib

Any suggestions?

Comment: And you want larger TTL on multicast packets for ...?

Comment: The same compiler on each platform?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov : The larger TTL is needed to cross a "long-distance" network

Comment: @Steve-o: yes, same compiler on each platform.

Comment: And the "long-distance" network is configured to forward multicast, right?

Comment: yes, @NikolaiNFetissov. But, beside the actually usage, I just want to set IP_MULTICAST_TTL  but windows7 does not allow me because the constant is defined wrong..

Comment: I suggest that you aren't doing what you think you're doing. The recommendations in the KB article are quite clear. You could try doing the first option: use Winsock2.h and Wsock2.lib only.